# Create and access folder outside Apache Tomcat webapps folder

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, directory

My web application requires functionality where end users can upload content, that can be later downloaded or viewed by others, the problem with current scheme is If I create such folder as part of your web project under webapps, every time I do deploy your web application (*.war), the content of that directory will be lost (or overridden).

I think the best way to accomplish that is to create folder outside of standard tomcat webapps and access it from there, not sure how to do. Please point in correct direction.

I am using Tomcat 4.x soon will be moving to 6.x.

-SPD

Comment: Folks the issue resolved. 

Tomcat 4.x configuration.
I created the below context in server.xml and it worked.

<Context path="/downloads" docBase="C:/downloads" debug="0" privileged="true"/>


-Suresh

Answer (score 1):

create a folder in some location on your system and add that folder to your classpath. This may solve your problem. You have to store and retrive from this folder at runtime.